# Adding a parameter to a partial breaks all my expressions in that partial

Tags: handlebars.js, partials

I'm iterating over an array and generating a partial for every item, which returns a name. I added a parameter called text and set it to "hello!".

```
{{#each array}}
    {{> partial text="hello!" }}
{{/each}}
```

Adding the parameter to the partial causes the other 'name 'expression to not display. Instead, only "hello!" is shown. Here is the code for my partial:

```
{{ text }}
{{ name }}
```

Comment: Can you please share your partial definition and your JSON data as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is, that you're losing your scope inside that partial, which is the normal behaviour handlebars has.

When you call a partial all parameters that are available within your template won't be there anymore, if you dont pass them to that partial.

So if you want to access {{ name }} inside your partial. you have to call your partial like so :

```
{{> partial text="hello!" name=name }}
```

Partials are similar to calling a function in other programming languages, except for that you name your parameters in the call.

Take a look at this pseudo code:

```
foo = "Hello world!"
myPartial(bar=foo);

function myPartial(bar) {
  echo bar; // bar will be "Hello world!"
}
```

Maybe it helps.

[Also feel free to check the handlebars partial documentation to guide you further](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)